# Getting count of Checkbox array in php, displaying specific value in textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, checkbox

is there a way i can get the count of an array of checkboxes, say there are like 4 arrays(`yeswb[], yesab[], yesal[], yesvb[]`). In need to get the count of the arrays `yeswb[], yesab[], yesal[]` and `yesvb[]`, compare the largest count amongst them and display a specific value on a textfield.

```
<form action="checkbox.php" method="POST">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                        <th>Indicator/Symptom</th>
                                            <th>Yes</th>
                                            <th>No</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="gradeA"> 
                                        <td>Headache</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yeswb[]" value="Headache"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="nowb[]" value="No Headache"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td>Diarrhoea</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yeswb[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="nowb[]" value="No"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td>Vomiting</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yeswb[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="nowb[]" value="No"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td>Constipation</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yeswb[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="nowb[]" value="No"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td>Nausea</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yeswb[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="nowb[]" value="No"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td>No Appetite</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yeswb[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="nowb[]" value="No"></td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td>Sneezing</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yesab[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="noab[]" value="No"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td>Runny Nose</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yesab[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="noab[]" value="No"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td>Coughing</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yesab[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="noab[]" value="No"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td>Itchy eyes and nose</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yesab[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="noab[]" value="No"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td> Watery eyes</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yesab[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="noab[]" value="No"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td>Fatigue</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yesvb[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="novb[]" value="No"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td>Chills & Fever</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yesvb[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="novb[]" value="No"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td>Muscle/Joint aches</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yesvb[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="novb[]" value="No"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td> Swollen Lymph Nodes</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yesvb[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="novb[]" value="No"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td>Expanding Rash</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yesvb[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="novb[]" value="No"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td>Redrash</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yesal[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="noal[]" value="No"></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td>Wheezing</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yesal[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="noal[]" value="No"></td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="gradeA">
                                        <td>Swollenness</td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="yesal[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="noal[]" value="No"></td>

                                    </tr>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table> 
                                </form>
```

say for example the count of `yeswb[]` is 4, the count of `yesab[]` is 3 and the count of `yesvb[]` is 1, how will I generate a statement like `yeswb[] wins`  in a textfield? (because with a count of 4 `yeswb[]`is the greatest)
thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems like you've answered your own question. Simply use the [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function and compare.

Comment: @alanlittle, how do i implement this count()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `checkbox.php`

```
$mFinalArray = [];
foreach($_POST as $index => $post){
    $mFinalArray[$index] = count($post);
}

    $biggestCategory = array_search(max($mFinalArray), $mFinalArray);

    print_r($mFinalArray);

    print_r($biggestCategory);
```

Example of the form selected :

[image]

Output :

```
Array
(
    [yeswb] = 3
    [yesab] = 2
    [yesvb] = 2
)

yeswb
```

Information :

`$index` : key of array (yeswb, yesab, yesvb)

`$post`  : current array in loop

`$_POST` : an array of all `$_POST` variables

*Also, in your form change

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="yeswb[]" value="Headache"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="nowb[]" value="No Headache"></td>
```

To

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="yeswb[]" value="Yes"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="nowb[]" value="No"></td>
```